# How to show a space is an invariant core for a strongly continuous semigroup?

Tags: stochastic-calculus, semigroups-of-operators

This question comes from a paper [2015(Kolokoltsov)](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=on%20fully%20mixed%20and%20multi%20dimensional%20extension%20of%20the%20caputo%20and%20riemann%20liouville&oq=on%20fully%20mixed%20and%20multi%20dimensional%20extension%20of%20the%20caputo%20and%20Riemann%20li) Theorem 4.1.
In the end of the proof i), “Applying to $T_t$ the procedure applied above to $T_t^h$ shows that $T_t$ defines also a strongly continuous semigroup in $C^1(\infty,b]$, and hence $C^1(\infty,b]$ is an invariant core for $T_t$ ”.

My question is Why  $C^1(\infty,b]$ is an invariant core for $T_t$ ?